# kind cluster - how to see docker-images that are loaded?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

To test my images I normally load them into my kind cluster by running on my macOS laptop something like  ...

```
kind load docker-image foo/bar-1.0.0:latest
```

How do I see what images have already been loaded ?

kind = https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind

Comment: Do you mean to list all images like 
 `docker images`? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: @PjoterS yes but for INSIDE the kind cluster itself. Answer from Arghya has given  me enough to move on.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Get name of a node by running `kubectl get nodes`.

Get into the node by running `docker exec -ti <nodename> bash`

After getting into the node you can just run `crictl images` to see images loaded on that node.

Comment: Perfect. I was not aware of `crictl`. For anyone else interested ... more details on it at https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md

Answer (score 9):

For first cluster in the list, write this command:

```
docker exec -it $(kind get clusters | head -1)-control-plane crictl images
```

For specific cluster, write this command:

```
docker exec -it ${CLUSTER_NAME}-control-plane crictl images
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command and it will show all images loaded on the kind node

```
kubectl get nodes kind-control-plane -o yaml
```